# Getting error: bash: parse_git_branch: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, sudo, git-bash

I am running the command:

```
sudo bash
```

But I keep getting an error on my terminal that says,

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

Here is my `.bash_profile` file

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w - \$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export EDITOR='subl -w'



export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but you can do `git branch --show-current`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `parse_git_branch` is defined in `.bash_profile`, but not exported. When you run `sudo bash`, it starts an *nonlogin* shell that sources `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`. `PS1` was exported and so is defined in the new shell, but `parse_git_branch` is not.

Typically, you would define both `PS1` and `parse_git_branch` in `.bashrc` and export neither of them. macOS is a little different from Linux, in that a terminal emulator starts a login shell instead of an ordinary interactive shell. A good practice is to put the definitions in `.bashrc`, then source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`.

Here's how I would split up your existing `.bash_profile`:

In `.bashrc`:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w - \$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

In `.bash_profile`:

```
# Many of the paths you were adding to PATH should already be
# there in the default configuration; run /usr/lib/path_helper
# to see the default.
PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export EDITOR='subl -w'
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue in my case was adding the *hashbang* (`#!/bin/bash` - or could be `tcsh` in the end in your case) to the beginning of my `.bashrc`.

Without hashbang at the top of `.bashrc` the function still applied to PS1 but only within the main partition (on my SSD), but when I tried to manipulate git repositories on another mount (an extra HDD) I had this message.

So just adding `#!/bin/bash` and then reloading `.bashrc` (by doing `source ~.bashrc`) fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your terminal and read the startup logs - initial lines. It should log which file has issues and what is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

By looking at your *.bash_profile*, it seems you have forgotten to add the keyword *function* before parse_git_branch() {}

Try changing to,

```
function parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

After that, reload your *.bash_profile* and see if it works.

Reference: [Functions in Bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html).

Comment: Hello, mattias. Unfortunately it didn't work. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: `function` is an optional `bash` extension; its use is not even recommended.

Comment: (...and its habit of advising/showcasing/demonstrating things that are considered bad practice is part of why linking to the ABS is frowned on).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What is ABS an abbreviation for?

Comment: Heh -- the *other* common bash guide by TLDP, the "Advanced" Bash Scripting guide. I see you linked into the introductory one -- apologies about the confusion there; that said, the criticism generally applies. BTW, in terms of bash references/resources that are worth recommending -- see the [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), the [Bash Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/), and of course [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).